# MySQL remove zeros from decimal part if the number is whole

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have a sales table with `price` column as `decimal(8, 2)` and I'm running the query below to get the total price

```
select sum(case when status = 1 then price * quantity when status = 2 then price * quantity * -1 else 0 end) as total from sales;
```

It's working perfectly but my results are usually intergers so I end up with trailing zeros all the time. It'd be nice to just return the whole number if there is no decimal part

Comment: `... CAST(SUM(...) AS UNSIGNED) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like [akina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10138734/akina) said in his comment ...

you can [cast](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/cast/) the sum result to UNSIGNED  INTEGER

```
select 
CAST(sum(case when status = 1 then price * quantity when status = 2 then price * quantity * -1 else 0 end) AS UNSIGNED)
 as total from sales;
```